# Selenium-Wire in Java to set proxy with authentication

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

Is the selenium-wire library available in Java? I am trying to set socks5 proxy with username/password to my selenium browser, when I was using Python I used selenium-wire to achieve this, but I don't know how to do that in Java. If selenium-wire is not available in Java any other library to do socks5 proxy with username/password in Java selenium?